# Loading external data into a PhoneGap app using an API

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to communicate with my server with an API.

**My first question: Is it possible to write my own API and use it with Phonegap ?**

This app would :

- send the login password in SHA1.
- The API would return the token or SLUG would be stored locally and which would allow (or not) to access the contents of the app : in other words, successful or not authentication.

After successful authentication, the app sends a POST request to the API with the value of the token to retrieve data related to the token (user-related) .

Query results retrieved in JSON.

**My second question: how it can work and what do I need ?**

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitively possible to do everything you ask for. You can use ajax calls from client side to server side and get back all the data you need, i.e. the connection token.

So, for you points:

1. "Send the login/password in SHA1": get the login/password couple from the DOM, convert in SHA256 (better than SHA1), send to your server via ajax
2. get back the result from you server in JSON format. If success, get the token given and store locally temporary
3. Use the token to call every communication API from your client to your server, so you'll be sure about the user identity

I would also suggest to use a https protocol in case of personal data are managed by your app.

What do you need? JS and/or jQuery experience, (possibly) manage all code on the client side and the server side too, time to develop. I also suggest you to use a great online tool called [Runscope](https://www.runscope.com) to track all your client/server communication and debug.

//// EDIT ////

- How to interact with your API: I'm a client side dev, so I can drop you a snippet to login:

> `email = $("#email").val();
>
>   password = $("#password").val();
>   var newdatatosend = email+"/"+password;
>
>       var datatosend = {"login": window.btoa(newdatatosend) };
>   $.ajax({
>               type: "POST",
>               url: url_main+url_api+url_login, 
>               dataType: 'json',
>               data: JSON.stringify(datatosend), 
>               contentType: "application/json"
>           })
>           .done(function(data) {
>   // Here are data received from the server: the connection token
>   })`

- As you can read, I receive the token from the server (if my credentials are genuine) and I store it in a SessionStorage (a local storage that is empty when the app will be closed). Anyway, you should manage the expiration time of the token on the server side (2 hours? 12 hours?). So, when the client try to use its old stored token, you should ask to login again to refresh the session.
- To use the session storage you simply use set/get functions:

  > ```
  > sessionStorage.setItem('mytoken', token);
  > var token = sessionStorage.getItem('mytoken');
  > ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already knew much of the overall operation. What I would have liked, it was how to make the interactions with the API

I would also like to know how the token works, how to store it and possibly advices on its use (validity duration of the particular token)

I know JavaScript and JQuery with a small preference for JQuery.
I would like a maximum of thing is handled client side with a view to a significant user base in the future and to avoid using the maximum server.